# 'AllItems.aspx' of Document library 'Cannot be found'

Tags: document-library, 404

We have a production site that has been running fine, and have recently set up a staging site. Did a backup/restore of the content database, and did a site backup/restore. Everything works, except this 1 document library always says "The source cannot be found - 404" when we try to view the /{doclib}/Forms/AllItems.aspx page. SPD sees the library, and can see all of the files in it. From SPD, if I select Views > AllItems.aspx, it pre-loads the page in SPD, and shows the 1 file in there. If I select to view it in the browser, I end up with the 404.

Any ideas? I renamed the old library, and created a new library with the original name, and the same issue occurs. We are also unable to view the files (such as an image) from their http url (http://site/doclib/image.jpg).

Edit: I just created a brand new library with a completely random name, and I'm able to view the AllItems page. Is there something broken in the Database with the library name I want?

Edit2: I've deleted the culprit library, hoping to clear out anything in the content db that may be broken. Created a new library with the name of what we need it to be named as, and got a 404.

Something has this name saved that is causing issues.

Comment: First of all, I'd recommend you to check your ULS logs (14\LOGS). 404 error in browser often has underlying records in ULS, which provide the real error message.

Answer (score 1):

Using SharePoint Manager (http://spm.codeplex.com/), check to see if the document library was actually deleted.

Then in IIS, make sure there isn't any virtual directory or such that matches the name of the document library.